# Getting average from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I can't seem to get the average from my variable output. It's either I'm getting NaN or zero.

My first output is:

```
console.log(data)
0: {nodeId: "53", SNR: "[38.2, 38, 37.9, 37.8, 37.6]", timestamp: 
"2019-09-05 00:00:17"}
```

Then I parse it to get only the SNR:

```
console.log(SNR);
["[38.2, 38, 37.9, 37.8, 37.6]"]
```

I tried the code below; but it keeps on giving me 0 and it can't seem 
      to see the numbers inside the square bracket:

```
      0[38.2, 38, 37.9, 37.8, 37.6]
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/data.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var SNR = [];
            for (var i in data) {
                SNR.push(data[i].SNR);
            }
            console.log(SNR);
            //const numbers = [80, 77, 88, 95, 68];
            const numbers = [SNR];
            //const grades = [SNR];
            //function getAvg(grades) {
            //const sum = 0;
            const sum = numbers.reduce((total, n) => total + n, 0);
            console.log(sum);
            //const total = grades.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
            //return total / grades.length;

            // const average = getAvg(grades);
            //console.log(average);

        },

        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Input data:

```
[{"nodeId":"53","SNR":"[38.2, 38, 37.9, 37.8, 37.6]","timestamp":"2019-09-05 00:00:17"},{"nodeId":"53","SNR":"[38.2, 37.9, 38.4, 37.9, 38.3]","timestamp":"2019-09-05 00:15:17"}]
```

Expected output (SNR has been parsed):

```
0: 37.9
1: 38.1
```

Comment: `SNR` is not an array, it's a string an will need to be parsed `JSON.parse(SNR)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var result = {};
        var data = [{ "nodeId": "53", "SNR": "[38.2, 38, 37.9, 37.8, 37.6]", "timestamp": "2019-09-05 00:00:17" }, { "nodeId": "53", "SNR": "[38.2, 37.9, 38.4, 37.9, 38.3]", "timestamp": "2019-09-05 00:15:17"}];

        $.each(data, function (i, e) {
            var sum = 0;
            snr = JSON.parse(e.SNR);
            $.each(snr, function (j, f) {
                sum += f;
            });
            result[i]={ i: (sum / snr.length) };
        });
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Try this one.

Comment: how can i ignore change null values to 0?

Comment: you need to validate data before iterate. for more clarification please ask new question with sample data and comment a link here.

Answer (score 0):

If your data truly is as you depict, then the problem is rather obvious: `SNR` is a JSON-ish string depicting an array, not an actual array.

For a minimally invasive change to your code,

```
SNR.push(JSON.parse(data[i].SNR));
```

would probably be a good start.